# Sending data for querying from android app to Django server

Tags: javascript, android, django, cordova, ionic-framework

Hi and please excuse my english.

My problem is this, I need to use ionic-cordova to create an app that sends a simple string to server, this server was built with Django framework and I need to receive this string to perform a simple "SELECT received-string FROM some-table" and return the result back to the android app.

I know the basics to create and app using ionic-cordova, my problem lies with the server, I have no idea how can I receive data sent by the android app, should I use javascript or a django view can do it?, and if using javascript is the way, how can I make the query and return the results? (I'm guessing Ajax)

I write this, because frankly I don't know how to approach this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to create a django view:

```
    from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
    from .models import *
    @csrf_exempt
    def recibir(request):
        estado = ""
        if request.method == "POST":
            matricula = str(request.POST['matricula'])
            estado = Ordenes_Trabajo.objects.values('estado').filter(matricula_vehiculo=matricula).order_by('timestamp')[0].encode()
        else:
            estado= "La consulta no arrojo resultados" 
        return HttpResponse(estado)
```

And the android app sends HTTP requests to the and url in the server.